# Using Colab GPU locally

Tags: python, gpu

I have a Lenovo as computer, but there is no GPU installed. So when I run a machine learning program written in python, it runs it on my local CPU. I know that Colab provides us a GPU for free. To use it, I need to take the content of all the python files from my ML program and put it in this Colab notebook. It is not very convenient at this point. Is it possible to run in any ways my ML program from my computer using directly the Colab GPU without using the Colab Notebook directly.